# htaccess regex variable parameter

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm not used to regex and figure I've lost too many hours trying to resolve this, so thought I'd ask for help. I am trying to prettify the html extension.

My site will use URLs that have variable parameters. For example:

- mysite.com/article/this-is-an-entry
- mysite.com/article/this-is-an-entirely-different-entry

All will use .html as the extension.

In the htaccess file, I have tried

`RewriteRule ^(article\/[a-z].*)$ $1.html [NC,L]`

as well as slight variations of this, but cannot get this right. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: `[a-z].*` would demand one letter, and then allow for any amount of any arbitrary character after that. So your pattern should match both example URL formats already. _"but cannot get this right"_ - what happens - do you get a 404, a 500, ...?

Comment: You are trying to simply rewrite from `article/this-is-an-entry` to `article/this-is-an-entry.html`, yes? Your pattern would match that latter URL again, so then `article/this-is-an-entry.html` would get rewritten to `article/this-is-an-entry.html.html` next. And so on, and so forth - until you hit the internal redirect limit.

Comment: "You are trying to simply rewrite from article/this-is-an-entry to article/this-is-an-entry.html, yes?"

Yes, that's right. I get a 404 error with the notice "Object not found!"

Comment: You will either need to find a way to prevent `article/this-is-an-entry.html` from being rewritten again (like be more specific in your pattern, to not allow any dots for example) - or you combine this with a RewriteCond to check whether what was requested with `.html` appended to it matches an existing file, and only lets the rewrite proceed in that case. (Do some research on the details for that, this is a pretty common thing.)

Comment: @CBroe Good spot, but FYI the simplest solution is to use `END` instead of `L` in the flags. See my answer below.

Comment: Thank you CBroe for your help on this. I had no idea Apache re-processed/cycled these kind of rewrites - I rarely need to dabble with the server - but this was a big help in understanding what the issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, let's look at the regex you have:

> ^(article/[a-z].*)$

This matches exactly the string "article/", followed by at least one letter (case insensitive due to the `NC` flag), followed by zero or more of anything. It's quite broad, but should match the examples you gave.

One way to test that it's matching is to add the `R=temp` flag to the rule, which tells Apache to *redirect the browser to the new URL* (I recommend using "=temp" to stop the browser caching the redirect and making later testing harder). You can then observe (e.g. in your browser's F12 debug console) the original request and the redirected one.

> RewriteRule ^(article/[a-z].*)$ $1.html [NC,L,R=temp]

However, as CBroe points out, your rule will match *again* on the target URL, so you need to prevent that. A simple way would be to use [the `END` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end) instead of `L`:

> Using the [END] flag terminates not only the current round of rewrite processing (like [L]) but also prevents any subsequent rewrite processing from occurring in per-directory (htaccess) context.

So:

> RewriteRule ^(article/[a-z].*)$ $1.html [NC,END]

Alternatively, you can make your pattern stricter, such as changing the `.` ("anything") to `[^.]` ("anything other than a dot"):

> ^(article/[a-z][^.]*)$

To be even more specific, you can add a `RewriteCond` with an extra pattern to *not* apply the rule to, such as "anything ending `.html`".

Comment: This did the trick.

Thank you for taking the time to explain why this was not working. I gained a better understanding of how Apache processes re-writes and applies them, which will help in the future. 

Thanks again!